# ObjectContext.CreateObject<T>: Create ComplexObject

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, reflection

Could someone please explain the following:

I have the following code that creates an instance of a type specified:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = this._dbContext.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObject").MakeGenericMethod(instanceType);
object invokedObject = methodInfo.Invoke(this._dbContext, null);
```

Where the `_dbContext` in my Entity Model.

When I try to create an instance of the following class all is happy and it works:

```
public partial class User : EntityObject
{
 ....
}
```

But when I try the same within the following class - I receive an error:

*The member with identity 'MyNamespace.Account' does not exist in the metadata collection.*

```
public partial class Account : ComplexObject
{
....
}
```

Could someone please explain why I'm able to create an instance / object of an `EntityObject` but not a `ComplexObject` ?

Many thanks!!

[UPDATE]

```
    public ObjectSet<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_Users == null))
            {
                _Users = base.CreateObjectSet<User>("Users");
            }
            return _Users;
        }
    }
    private ObjectSet<User> _Users;
```

Comment: Show the `DbSet<?>` your context contains

Comment: `DbSet<?>` ... Can't find any object of that type in my Designer.cs file. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Your `Entity Framework` context is `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`?

Comment: Then show the `ObjectSet<?>` your context contains

Comment: The `ObjectSet` only contains the `User` declaration - I've updated my original question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 2 problems:

1. As noted in your updated question, your `context` doesn't contain reference to `Account`, you need to add it before requesting it (using the `'CreateObject'` method) from the context:

   ```
   public ObjectSet<Account> Accounts
   {
       get
       {
           if ((_Accounts == null))
           {
               _Accounts = base.CreateObjectSet<Account>("Accounts");
           }
           return _Accounts;
       }
   }

   private ObjectSet<Account> _Accounts;
   ```
2. Since your `Account` is a `ComplexType` i don't think you'll be able to use it as an `ObjectSet<>`, since `ComplexType` does not have an `Identity` and can only be used as a part of a parent `Entity`.